# share image as Document in Whatsapp programmatically android Kotlin

Tags: android, image, kotlin, whatsapp

I want to send image through Whatsapp from Android App. I don't want any compression in the image while sending it to receiver , therefore it is required for me to send the image as a **Document**. Following are the code to send the image through Whatsapp but the image is sent as **Image** which causes change in image pixel value due to compression. how do i send the image as **Document**.

```
          // whatsapp share code begin
                val share = Intent()
                share.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                share.type = "application/pdf"
                  
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireActivity(), "my.example.application.provider", file!!))
                share.setPackage("com.whatsapp.w4b")
                activity?.startActivity(share)

         // whatsapp share code end
```